# How to keep columns in the same sequence while transposing the dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a dataframe df with the columns

```
cycle_end_date | trigger | deliver | cost
```

when i do `df.transpose()`

I get the following result

```
        cycle_end_date_1 | cycle_end_date_2 | cycle_end_date_3
cost
deliver
trigger
```

which is fine but how do i preserve the sequence of my index? It should come in the same sequence that is `trigger, deliver, cost`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .loc should let you reorder the indexes:

```
df.loc[['cost', 'deliver', 'trigger']]
```

Comment: This does not work after transposing. It gives me this: KeyError: "None of [['bounced_email', 'cycle_end_date']] are in the [index]"

Comment: @coder_bg Based on your exemple, cycle_end_date is transpose as the new columns, but I didn't see bounced_email. Can you share an exemple of original data and expected output please?

Comment: It was only an example, i used your same exact code but was not able to do it.

Comment: You should apply the .loc[] after the transpose (sorry I didn't specify it). And also, adapt the name of indexes on what you have as index in your dataframe after transpose it. If you have not 'cost' as an index in your dataframe, .loc['cost'] will return a KeyError.